# Chi square test of good fitting

Tags: python, t-test, chi-squared-test, fitting

I am trying to find the best way to fit my data, it looks like a modified sigmoid (code below). The problem I have is that my critical chisquare value is very high, am I then correctly calculating the degrees of freedom ? In my opinion it should be the number of data points minus the parameters of my function ?  Then what I'd like to do is measure the chisquare of my modified sigmoid vs the 'classical' one and 'see' which one fits better by looking at the $\chi^2$ value. Thank you for any help

````
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import chisquare
import scipy.stats as stats
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import warnings

# Sigmoid function
def sigmoid(x, L, x0, b):
    return L / (1 + np.exp(-(x-x0))) + b

# Modified sigmoid function
def modified_sigmoid(x, L, x0, b, c, e):
    y = (L * (np.exp(np.maximum(x - x0, 0) * e) + 1 / (x + 1e-7))) / (1 + np.exp(-c * (x - x0))) + b
    return y


# Generate x values
x = np.linspace(0, 100, 1000)

# Compute y values for the modified sigmoid
y_data = modified_sigmoid(x, 100, 50, 10, 1, -.1)

# Add random noise to y_neg
noise = np.random.normal(0, 2, len(y_neg))
y_data += noise

# Fit the modified + random data
p0 = [90, 45, 8, 2, -.1]
popt, cov = curve_fit(modified_sigmoid, x, y_data, p0 = p0, maxfev = 5000)
sigmo_fit = modified_sigmoid(x, *popt)

# Calculate the chi-square for goodness of fitting
chi2 = chisquare(y_data, sigmo_fit)
print(chi2)
# Define the significance level
alpha = 0.05
# Calculate the critical chi-square value
df = len(x) - 1
critical_value = stats.chi2.ppf(1 - alpha, df)
print(critical_value)

# Plot the generated data and fit
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
plt.scatter(x, y_data, label='Generated Data')
plt.plot(x, sigmo_fit, label = 'Fit', color = 'red')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Generated Data vs Fit comparison')
plt.legend()
plt.show()```
````